# Using Enum.map to create a key map

Tags: elixir

simple question, I have these 2 maps

```elixir
[{"Africa", 1}, {"America", 2}, {"Europe", 3}]
```

```elixir
[{"Congo", 1, 1}, {"France", 2, 3}, {"Spain", 3, 3}, {"USA", 4, 2}, {"Egypt", 5, 1}]
```

I want to use Enum.map and Enum.filter to get below result

```elixir
[
  Africa: [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 1}],
  America: [{"USA", 4}],
  Europe: [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]
]
```

I have tried with the below combination but Im not getting the expected result. Can you give some help?

```elixir
Enum.map(
  [{"Africa", 1}, {"America", 2}, {"Europe", 3}],
  fn {continent_name, continent_id} ->
    Enum.filter(
      [{"Congo", 1, 1}, {"France", 2, 3}, {"Spain", 3, 3}, {"USA", 4, 2}, {"Egypt", 5, 1}],
      fn {country_name, country_id, country_continent_id} ->
        if continent_id == country_continent_id do
          [continent_name: [{country_name, country_id}]]
        end
      end
    )
  end
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't use filter, but let me know if this works for you.

```elixir
continents = [{"Africa", 1}, {"America", 2}, {"Europe", 3}]
countries = [{"Congo", 1, 1}, {"France", 2, 3}, {"Spain", 3, 3}, {"USA", 4, 2}, {"Egypt", 5, 1}]

##Place countries by continent id in a map
countries_by_continent = Enum.reduce(countries,%{}, fn({name, country_id, continent_id}, countries_map) ->
  case Map.get(countries_map, continent_id) do
    nil ->   Map.put(countries_map, continent_id, [{name, country_id}])
    current_countries -> Map.put(countries_map, continent_id, current_countries ++ [{name, country_id}])
  end
end)

Enum.map(continents, fn({continent_name, continent_id}) ->
  ["#{continent_name}": Map.get(countries_by_continent, continent_id)]
end)
```

Comment: No. 
Expected result is ```[
  ["Africa": [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 5}]],
  ["America": [{"USA", 4}]],
  ["Europe": [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]]
]```

Comment: but the result of the script you have provided is ```[
  [Africa: [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 5}]],
  [America: [{"USA", 4}]],
  [Europe: [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]]
]```

Comment: in other words, continent names should be strings

Comment: its because your expecting a Keyword list as result, if you expect a string you must use, touples. Like the solutoin from TheAnh

Comment: you n change  do Atom.to_string when traversing the results

Comment: In Elixir a double quoted atom its and atom.

iex(99)> :"Africa"
:Africa

Answer (score 1):

I would like to use `Enum.group_by/3`

```
iex()> cons = [{"Africa", 1}, {"America", 2}, {"Europe", 3}]
iex()> countries = [{"Congo", 1, 1}, {"France", 2, 3}, {"Spain", 3, 3}, {"USA", 4, 2}, {"Egypt", 5, 1}]
iex()> countries = Enum.group_by(countries, fn {_, _, group_key} -> group_key end, fn {country, val, _} -> {country, val} end) |> Enum.into([])
[
  {1, [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 5}]},
  {2, [{"USA", 4}]},
  {3, [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]}
]
iex()> for {con, key_to_match} <- cons, {k, grouped_country} <- countries, key_to_match == k do
...()> [{String.to_atom(con), grouped_country}]
...()> end
[
  [Africa: [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 5}]],
  [America: [{"USA", 4}]],
  [Europe: [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not the expected result

Comment: Expected result:
```[ ["Africa": [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 5}]], ["America": [{"USA", 4}]], ["Europe": [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]] ]```

Comment: in other words, the result is a list of ```[ "continent": [{"country1", contry_id},{"country2", contry_id}, .....]]``` where the continent is inside quotes (printed as string) and followed by a column

Comment: it just that I forgot the type of such variable ```"key": value```, I think it's a map, but im' not sure

Comment: so that is keyword list https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html#keyword-lists and your key  is atom. You can use `String.to_atom/1`

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```elixir
continents =
  [{"Africa", 1}, {"America", 2}, {"Europe", 3}]
  |> Map.new(fn {a, b} -> {b, String.to_atom(a)} end)

[
  {"Congo", 1, 1},
  {"France", 2, 3},
  {"Spain", 3, 3},
  {"USA", 4, 2},
  {"Egypt", 5, 1}
]
|> Enum.group_by(&elem(&1, 2), &Tuple.delete_at(&1, 2))
|> Enum.map(fn {id, list} -> {continents[id], list} end)
```

Output:

```elixir
[
  Africa: [{"Congo", 1}, {"Egypt", 5}],
  America: [{"USA", 4}],
  Europe: [{"France", 2}, {"Spain", 3}]
]
```

Comment: That's a really functional approach Adam, so nice

Answer (score 1):

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension is extremely underrated. This is probably the easiest way to go.

```rb
(for {ct, cti} <- continents,
     {cy, cyi, cycti} <- countries, cti == cycti,
  do: {String.to_atom(ct), {cy, cyi}})
|> Enum.reduce([], fn {k, v}, acc ->
  Keyword.update(acc, k, [v], fn l -> [v | l] end)
end)

#⇒ [
#    Africa: [{"Egypt", 5}, {"Congo", 1}],
#    America: [{"USA", 4}],
#    Europe: [{"Spain", 3}, {"France", 2}]
#  ]
```

On the first step we go through continents, then through countries *and* filter the countries by continents *inplace*.